# Problem with astronomy and astrophysics template

Tags: templates, abstract

I am writing a stellar atlas and I am using the astronomy and astrophysics template in latex but when making a document the template makes an abstract without me asking. How do i delete the abstract ?

(Template can be found on the website https://www.aanda.org/for-authors)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code? Not all people here are willing to follow an external link ...

Comment: why use a journal template at all if you don't need to follow its design for this case?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My professor put it in the assingment that we had to use this template( I dont see the point if it either)

Comment: @Mensch Do you want the code of the template or my document

Comment: As a best practice when asking a question, a MWE (Minimal Working Example) should be included. Can you provide yours, please?